# Ktor doesn't log exceptions

Tags: kotlin, logging, ktor

Ktor (1.4.2) seems to be suppresing exceptions. According to [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html#logging-exceptions) I need to re-throw exception like this

```
install(StatusPages) {
    exception<Throwable> { ex ->
        val callstack: String = ....
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                ApiError(ex.javaClass.simpleName, ex.message ?: "Empty Message", callstack)
        )
        throw ex
    }
}
```

I wrote wrapper around `Logger` interface to make sure it's calling `Logger.error()` (it doesn't) and configured it like this

```
install(CallLogging) {
            level = org.slf4j.event.Level.INFO
            logger = Log4j2Wrapper(logger2)
        }
```

I can see `INFO`-level logs. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the problem is in rather akward design of ktor api. Summary of my findings:

Contrary to common expectation to see log events of specified log level **and above** it doesn't that way with `CallLogging`. [It expects](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/1.4.2/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/jvm/src/io/ktor/features/CallLogging.kt#L158-L164) exact match of the logging level which minimizes usefulness of this feature.

You need to overwrite logger specified in `ApplicationEnvironment.log`. But if you follow official ktor examples and do it like this

```
val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port) {
  applicationEngineEnvironment {
      log = YOUR_LOGGER
  }
}
```

it won't work because value `call.application.environment` inside function `io.ktor.server.engine.defaultEnginePipeline(env)` is still original one, created from logger name in config file or NOP logger.

Hence you'll need to initialize your server like this

```
val env = applicationEngineEnvironment {
    log = YOUR_LOGGER
    module {
        install(CallLogging) {
            level = org.slf4j.event.Level.INFO
        }
        install(StatusPages) {
            exception<Throwable> { ex ->
                val callstack: String = ...
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                        ApiError(ex.javaClass.simpleName, ex.message ?: "Empty Message", callstack)
                )
                throw ex
            }
        }

        routing {
        }
    }

    connector {
        host = "0.0.0.0"
        port = ...
    }
}

val server = embeddedServer(Netty, env)
```